# How to test download api using karate

Tags: karate

I have an api for file download (*txt,*.doc,*.csv) using spring framework in java.i wanted to do acceptance testing using karate .how can i do that.

here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(String param) throws 
IOException {
InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(file.length())
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .body(resource);
```

}

Answer (score 4):

See line number 16 in this example [`upload.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/upload/upload.feature#L16)

It is a normal `get`