# demo.headers.headers-single: [java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: authInfo.authTime

Tags: karate

When i try to build an karate , i am getting

**demo.headers.headers-single: [java.lang.RuntimeException: javascript evaluation failed: authInfo.authTime**
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:115)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.updateBindingsAndEval(ScriptBindings.java:103)
    at com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.evalInNashorn(ScriptBindings.java:88)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsExpression(Script.java:362)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:284)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalKarateExpression(Script.java:170)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:598)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:524)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:305)
    at ✽.* def time = authInfo.authTime(demo/headers/headers-single.feature:8)

**Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "authInfo" is not defined in  at line number 1**
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454)

Comment: looks pretty clear to me. also please can you mark questions as accepted, for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49081764/143475

Comment: i have tried by skipping test cases . it was working fine. but i need test cases for those Scenarios  with testing reports. i do accept all my questions asked.

Comment: my reputation is below 15 ,so i am not able to accept.please answer this question i may get more reputation . then can easily accept

Comment: the authInfo variable is not set. unless you provide a working example, no one will be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve